# Ionic2 Scroll in Expandable Header

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, ionic2

I am using Ionic 2, and have implemented an Expandable Header based on [this tutorial](https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-a-custom-expandable-header-component-for-ionic-2/).

It works perfectly, except I have two issues:

1. As you can see, all the search items are 0.7 opaque. This is correct, however the **background of the items should have a 1.0 opacity**.
2. When there are **No Results** (i.e. no items in the scroll list). The Expandable Header **won't collapse**. There are not items to scroll up on, so it won't resize the header.
3. After I apply a filter (and even clear it again), the [infinite scroll](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/infinite-scroll/InfiniteScroll/) `(ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)"` event does not fire when I scroll to the bottom of the page.

[image]

Here is my code. Apologies that it's so much, I don't want to leave out something relevant.

Any advise appreciated.

**html**

```
<ion-header>
  <expandable-header [scrollArea]="mycontent" headerHeight="{{isIOS ? 270 : 247}}">

    <ion-item class="search-item searchtext">
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col class="col-search">
          <ion-searchbar class="ion-searchtext" id="ion-searchtext" [(ngModel)]="searchQueryText" (change)="onChangeText($event)" (ionClear)="onCancelText($event)"
            (ionInput)="onInputText($event)" placeholder="Keyword Search" debounce="1" [showCancelButton]="isIOS"></ion-searchbar>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col class="col-cancel" *ngIf="!isIOS">
          <button ion-button *ngIf="!isIOS && searchQueryText" (click)="onCancelText($event)" color="primary" clear small>
        <p class="small-text-search search-cancel">Cancel</p>
      </button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item class="search-item">
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col class="col-search">
          <ion-searchbar id="ion-locationbar" [(ngModel)]="searchQueryLocation" (ionClear)="onCancelLocation($event)" (ionInput)="onInputLocation($event)"
            (click)="presentFilterMap()" placeholder="Location" debounce="1" [showCancelButton]="true"></ion-searchbar>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col class="col-cancel" *ngIf="!isIOS">
          <button ion-button *ngIf="!isIOS && searchQueryLocation" (click)="onCancelLocation($event)" color="primary" clear small>
        <p class="small-text-search search-cancel">Cancel</p>
      </button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item class="search-item">
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col class="col-search">
          <ion-searchbar id="ion-locationbar" [(ngModel)]="searchQuerySectors" (ionClear)="onCancelSectors($event)" (ionInput)="onInputSectors($event)"
            (click)="presentFilterCategories()" placeholder="Sectors" debounce="1" [showCancelButton]="true"></ion-searchbar>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col class="col-cancel" *ngIf="!isIOS">
          <button ion-button *ngIf="!isIOS && searchQuerySectors" (click)="onCancelSectors($event)" color="primary" clear small>
        <p class="small-text-search search-cancel">Cancel</p>
      </button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item class="search-item">
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col class="col-search">
          <ion-searchbar id="ion-locationbar" [(ngModel)]="searchQueryRating" (ionClear)="onCancelRating($event)" (ionInput)="onInputRating($event)"
            (click)="presentFilterRating()" placeholder="Star Rating" debounce="1" [showCancelButton]="true"></ion-searchbar>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col class="col-cancel" *ngIf="!isIOS">
          <button ion-button *ngIf="!isIOS && searchQueryRating" (click)="onCancelRating($event)" color="primary" clear small>
        <p class="small-text-search search-cancel">Cancel</p>
      </button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item class="search-item">
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col class="col-search">
          <ion-searchbar id="ion-locationbar" [(ngModel)]="searchQueryTime" (ionClear)="onCancelTime($event)" (ionInput)="onInputTime($event)"
            (click)="presentFilterTime()" placeholder="Last Online" debounce="1" [showCancelButton]="true"></ion-searchbar>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col class="col-cancel" *ngIf="!isIOS">
          <button ion-button *ngIf="!isIOS && searchQueryTime" (click)="onCancelTime($event)" color="primary" clear small>
        <p class="small-text-search search-cancel">Cancel</p>
      </button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-item>

  </expandable-header>

  <ion-navbar color="primary">

    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>

    <ion-title class="search-title-text">
      Market
    </ion-title>

    <div class="clear-all" *ngIf="searchQueryText || searchQueryLocation || searchQuerySectors || searchQueryRating || searchQueryTime"
      (click)="clearFilters($event)">
      <p class="clear-all-text {{isIOS ? 'clear-all-text-ios' : ''}}">Clear all</p>
      </div>

  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding class="content-wanted" id="search-content" fullscreen #mycontent>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item-sliding #slidingItem *ngFor="let item of myModels">
      <ion-item class="item-search-wanted" (click)="itemTapped($event, item, true)" (press)="openSlide(slidingItem, item, $event)">
```

**css**

```
.ios, .md {
    page-home {
        ion-item {
            width: 92%;
            margin: 4%;
            padding-left: 10px !important;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            background-color: #fff;
            opacity: 0.7;
            font-size: 0.9em;
            transition: 0.2s linear;
        } 
    } 
}

expandable-header .element.style {
    min-height: 6px;
}

expandable-header .label-md {
    margin: -16px 2px -4px -18px;
}

expandable-header .searchtext .label-md {
    margin: -10px 2px -4px -18px;
}

expandable-header .searchtext .label-ios {
    margin: 25px 2px -4px -4px;
}

expandable-header .label-ios {
    margin: -4px 2px -4px -4px;
}

.toolbar-ios ion-title {
    padding: 13px 90px 3px !important;
}

.toolbar-ios {
    padding-top: 15px;
}

expandable-header .search-item {
    opacity: 0.7 !important;
}

expandable-header .item-md.item-block .item-inner {
    padding-right: 8px;
    border-bottom: 0px solid #dedede;
}

expandable-header .searchbar-md {
    width: 213%;
}

expandable-header .button-clear-md {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 18px;
}

expandable-header .searchbar-clear-icon { 
    display: none !important; 
}

.clear-all-text {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 85%;
    padding-right: 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.clear-all-text-ios {
    padding-left: 250px;
}
```

**expandable-header.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'expandable-header',
    templateUrl: 'expandable-header.html'
})
export class ExpandableHeader {
    @Input('scrollArea') scrollArea: any;
    @Input('headerHeight') headerHeight: number;
    newHeaderHeight: any;
    constructor(public element: ElementRef, public renderer: Renderer) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        if (!this.scrollArea._scroll.enabled) {
            this.scrollArea.enableScrollListener();
        }
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.element.nativeElement, 'height', this.headerHeight + 'px');
        this.scrollArea.ionScroll.subscribe((ev) => {
            this.resizeHeader(ev);
        });
    }

    resizeHeader(ev) {
        ev.domWrite(() => {
            this.newHeaderHeight = this.headerHeight - ev.scrollTop;
            if (this.newHeaderHeight < 0) {
                this.newHeaderHeight = 0;
            }
            this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.element.nativeElement, 'height', this.newHeaderHeight + 'px');
            for (let headerElement of this.element.nativeElement.children) {
                let totalHeight = headerElement.offsetTop + headerElement.clientHeight;
                if (totalHeight > this.newHeaderHeight && !headerElement.isHidden) {
                    headerElement.isHidden = true;
                    this.renderer.setElementStyle(headerElement, 'opacity', '0');
                } else if (totalHeight <= this.newHeaderHeight && headerElement.isHidden) {
                    headerElement.isHidden = false;
                    this.renderer.setElementStyle(headerElement, 'opacity', '0.7');
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Question 3, re. infinite scroll can be fixed by setting the threshold attribute.