# Ionic 2 ion searchbar icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, ionic2

I am using Ionic2, and have the following [ion-searchbar](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/searchbar/Searchbar/):

[image]

**Question**

Is it possible to change the icon?  The default icon is a magnifying glass as you can see, I would like to change it to something else.

Thanks

Comment: Change the background image in your custom css for .searchbar-search-icon class

Comment: Thanks.  Is it also possible to change the icon colour?

Comment: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/7826  check this

Comment: After that check this https://www.joshmorony.com/a-guide-to-styling-an-ionic-2-application/ :P

Comment: thank you vey much

Comment: did you got the answer for scroll in expandable header?

Comment: Not yet, still trying to work it out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43252525/ionic2-scroll-in-expandable-header

Answer (score 2):

On ionic 3 I used "searchbar-search-icon" on ***variables.scss*** and worked for me.

```
.searchbar-search-icon {
  background-image: url("../assets/imgs/send-button.svg")!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change this variable?

```
$searchbar-ios-input-search-icon-svg
$searchbar-md-input-search-icon-svg
$searchbar-wp-input-search-icon-svg
```

Comment: It seems those variables are gone in the current v6 version. The above answer worked well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the search icon to one of the predefined [IonIcons](https://ionicons.com/) you can do something like this:

```
<ion-searchbar searchIcon="calendar"></ion-searchbar>
```

More information on the [Ionic searchbar official docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/searchbar).